# Find all following users where their username begins with myString

Tags: android, parse-platform

These are the columns of my Follow Table:

```
user (Pointer _User)
follower (Pointer _User)
```

What I want to do is to get all the user where

```
follower = currentUser
user.username begins with a certain string
```

I know that in lower-lever db (like mySQL) these data can all be fetched with a single query. 
Is it possible in parse?  If not, what's the best way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `currentUser` object is a `PFUser`

Note... I am program with parse in objective-c so I am not 100% sure this will run. But I feel like this is what your looking for... Your going to have to first query for all the followers who's `follower` field is equal to the current user.

Then join that query with a user query whose usernames or names, whatever, are equal to your string you pass in... ***beware*** the string you pass into the query is case-sensitive... i think...

So if a user in your app searches for BOB and the database has Bob stored... the query won't return Bob... It will just return nothing....

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.whereEqualTo("username", certainString);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> followerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Followers");
followerQuery.whereEqualTo("follower", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
followerQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("user", "follower", userQuery);
userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
   // comments now contains the comments for posts with images.
  }
});
```

***EDIT*** Going through Parse's Anypic project that does what you want... I feel that this is not possible... Your going to have to first make a query for the users in the followers table whose `followers` key is the current user. Then find the objects. Once the result is returned, iterate through the objects to whose names is contained within the `contains string`.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> followerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Followers");
followerQuery.whereEqualTo("username", certainString);
followerQuery.whereNotEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().username);
followerQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
    for (ParseObject element : list) {
      if (element.user == ParseUser.getCurrentUser()) {
        //This is a follower of the current user... append to a list object or whatever
      }
    }
    // update a label or table once the iteration is done.
  }
});
```

There still may be a solid solution for what you want to do in one query but I can't think of it right now... Ill come back to this post if I do.

Comment: In your code, exactly, where is the point where I join the queries? It seems that you are just no using the query on the Followers table

Comment: whoops i forgot to add that, one sec ill make an edit

Comment: I think this is wrong... But ill look it over some more, just notice the `matchesKeyInQuery()`

Comment: So I think the edited question is correct... But I didn't compile it so there may be syntax errors.... But I think you can get the jist of what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: the correct way to do such a thing is using matchesKeiInQuery, as jsetting32 said. followerQuery.whereMatchesQuery("user",userQuery);